# Change rows' color in Java JTable

Tags: java, colors, jtable, row, customization

I'm trying to change rows' color in Java JTable but I'm having some problems. This is the scenario: I have a table with some data to process and I would like, at the end of the processing (started through a button), the table is updated by coloring the lines in green, yellow or red depending on the outcome of the operations. Each processed object has a variable "outcome" that is set after processing. The table is created by the graphic editor of Netbeans (so it is not possible to modify the automatically generated code). I used this TableModel:

```
public class QuotationsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Quotation> quotationsList;

    public QuotationsTableModel(List<Quotation> quotationsList) {
        this.quotationsList= quotationsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if (quotationsList== null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.quotationsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (quotationsList== null) {
            return null;
        }
        Quotation quotation = quotationsList.get(rowIndex);
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return quotation.getQuotationNumber();
        }
        if (columnIndex == 1) {
            return quotation.getBillingType();
        }
        if (columnIndex == 2) {
            return quotation.getAdvance();
        }
        if (columnIndex == 3) {
            return quotation.getOutcome();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if (column == 0) {
            return "Number";
        } else if (column == 1) {
            return "Billing type";
        } else if (column == 2) {
            return "Advance";
        } else if (column == 3) {
            return "Outcome";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateTable() {
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

and I tried to reach the goal by creating the class:

```
public class CustomTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component original = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        Color background = table.getBackground();
        //Color grid = Color.YELLOW;

        Color fg = null;
        Color bg = null;


        if (isSelected) {
            super.setForeground(fg == null ? table.getSelectionForeground()
                                           : fg);
            super.setBackground(bg == null ? table.getSelectionBackground()
                                           : bg);
        } else {
            if (column == 3) {
                String outcome = String.valueOf(value);
                if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED")){
                  background = Color.GREEN;
                } else if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("PARTIAL")) {
                    background = Color.YELLOW;
                } else if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR")) {
                    background = Color.RED;
                }
            }
        }
    original.setBackground(background);

    return original;
    }
```

and then calling:

```
QuotationsTableModel quotationsTableModel= new QuotationsTableModel(quotationsList);
this.quotationsTable.setModel(quotationsTableModel);
this.quotationsTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTableRenderer());
```

but the outcome is colored only when selecting the line and, furthermore, once the line is selected, all values disappear except for the outcome. Can you help me please?

I found a working solution, maybe it can be useful to those that will come:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {


        Component original = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        Color background = table.getBackground();

        if (isSelected) {            
            original.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("TextField.selectionBackground"));
            original.setForeground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("TextField.selectionForeground"));
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);            
        } else {
            original.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("TextField.highlight"));
            original.setForeground(Color.BLACK);        
            if (column == 3) {
                String outcome = String.valueOf(value);
                if (outcome.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED")){
                  background = Color.GREEN;
                } else if (outcome.equalsIgnoreCase("PARTIAL")) {
                    background = Color.YELLOW;
                } else if (outcome.equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR")) {
                    background = Color.RED;
                }
                original.setBackground(background);
            }
        }

    return original;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain the working solution? I can only see that you have commented out the body of `CustomTableCellRenderer`. How can the coloring work with this?

Comment: Sorry, the comment was an error

Answer (score 0):

I have created below sample program using your `QuotationsTableModel` and `CustomTableRenderer` classes. Only problem I saw is in `CustomTableRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent()` method.

You were changing "Outcome" column color only when the row is not selected. Because of this, coloring did not work when a row is selected. To fix this problem, I removed `if (isSelected) {` part of the code. Run below example and see.

(When you post questions in the future, post a minimal, executable program like below example program. Then it's easier for others to run the scenario and see the problem.)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ColorTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Quotation> quotationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    quotationsList.add(new Quotation(111, "AA", 2500, "COMPLETED"));
    quotationsList.add(new Quotation(222, "BB", 4000, "PARTIAL"));
    quotationsList.add(new Quotation(333, "CC", 5000, "COMPLETED"));
    quotationsList.add(new Quotation(444, "DD", 1500, "SOME_OTHER_OUTCOME"));
    quotationsList.add(new Quotation(555, "EE", 3500, "ERROR"));
    QuotationsTableModel quotationsTableModel= new QuotationsTableModel(quotationsList);

    JTable quotationsTable = new JTable();
    quotationsTable.setModel(quotationsTableModel);
    quotationsTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTableRenderer());

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(quotationsTable));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class QuotationsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  private List<Quotation> quotationsList;

  public QuotationsTableModel(List<Quotation> quotationsList) {
    this.quotationsList= quotationsList;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
    if (quotationsList== null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return this.quotationsList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return 4;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (quotationsList== null) {
      return null;
    }
    Quotation quotation = quotationsList.get(rowIndex);
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      return quotation.getQuotationNumber();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 1) {
      return quotation.getBillingType();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 2) {
      return quotation.getAdvance();
    }
    if (columnIndex == 3) {
      return quotation.getOutcome();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    if (column == 0) {
      return "Number";
    } else if (column == 1) {
      return "Billing type";
    } else if (column == 2) {
      return "Advance";
    } else if (column == 3) {
      return "Outcome";
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void updateTable() {
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
  }
}

class CustomTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Component original = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    Color background = table.getBackground();
    //Color grid = Color.YELLOW;

    if (column == 3) {
      String outcome = String.valueOf(value);
      if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED")){
        background = Color.GREEN;
      } else if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("PARTIAL")) {
        background = Color.YELLOW;
      } else if (outcome .equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR")) {
        background = Color.RED;
      }
    }
    original.setBackground(background);

    return original;
  }
}

class Quotation {
  private int quotationNumber;
  private String billingType;
  private int advance;
  private String outcome;

  Quotation(int quotationNumber, String billingType, int advance, String outcome) {
    this.quotationNumber = quotationNumber;
    this.billingType = billingType;
    this.advance = advance;
    this.outcome = outcome;
  }

  int getQuotationNumber() {
    return quotationNumber;
  }

  String getBillingType() {
    return billingType;
  }

  int getAdvance() {
    return advance;
  }

  String getOutcome() {
    return outcome;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. For some reason this solution does not work for me, I had already tried it. I edited the first post adding my solution, maybe it can be useful to those that will come. Thank you.